# How to decide on nstart=x value to know how many attempts should be made at finding centroids?

Tags: r, k-means

`nstart=` x. How can its value be best determined to know how many attempts should be made to find the best centroids?

```
k2 <- kmeans(data, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this one:

https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/08/k-means-clustering-from-r-in-action/

Is a small guide for that issue.

BR